# Using ExcelSession.Workbook.Open from Delphi with Excel 365 causes worksheet to appear

Tags: excel, delphi, office365

Given a simple bit of code to open an Excel workbook and count the used columns and rows:

```
procedure GetWorksheetSize(const AFilename: String; var AUsedColumns, AUsedRows: Integer);
var
  ExcelSession, ExcelWorkbook, ExcelSheet: Variant;
begin
  ExcelSession := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
  ExcelSession.Visible := false;
  ExcelSession.UserControl := false;
  ExcelSession.Workbooks.Open(AFilename);
  ExcelWorkbook := ExcelSession.Workbooks[1];
  ExcelSheet := ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
  AUsedColumns := ExcelSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
  AUsedRows := ExcelSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
  ExcelWorkbook.Close;
  ExcelSession.Quit;
  ExcelSession := UnAssigned;
  ExcelWorkbook := UnAssigned;
  ExcelSheet := UnAssigned;
end;
```

It does not matter whether I write this in **Delphi 2005, XE2 or 10.3**, the result is the same; for **Excel 2013, 2016, and 2019** the procedure fills in the parameters without the user seeing the workbook. For **Excel 365**, the workbook appears briefly (without the **Excel** application window/ribbon), then disappears.

Does anyone know of a way to stop the workbook appearing? There is not a parameter on `Workbooks.Open` to tell it to open it without showing it.

Comment: I don't have Word365 installed to test on, but have you tried setting the .Left and .Top properties of the Word Application's main window so that it is located off-screen?  Iow, even if you can't stop it displaying, maybe you can get it to display where it can't be seen ...

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating (I don't have office365 so I can't test it...)